# Constrained Nonparametric Density Estimation with Right Censoring

Tags: r, survival, censoring, density-estimation

Is anyone aware if there is any available open source R (or other language) code which implements non-parametric estimation of the failure time density function subject to a monotonicity constraint on the failure time density function (example: decreasing density) using right-censored failure time data?

Answer (score 0):

The right-censored part will only let you estimate a right-tail probability, but obviously it does not allow you to estimate the shape of the density in the tail.  So really, all you need to do is to ignore the censored data and get a density estimate within the non-censored part of the distribution.  I'm not sure why you'd want to impose the constraint that the density must be decreasing, but if you want to do this you might be able to do it using the `scdensity package` (see documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scdensity/scdensity.pdf)).